# How to find out the highest array (with most items) within multiple arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have multiple arrays that need to be compared on how many items they contain and select the array with the highest value (= the array with the most items in it)

E.g. I have 3 arrays:

```
$a_arr = array( '0' => '45', '1' => '50', '2' => '100' );
$b_arr = array( '0' => 'apple' );
$c_arr = array( '0' => 'toyota', '1' => 'ferrari', );
```

Now I need to compare the number of items in these arrays and select the array with the highest number of items. So, the highest in these case would be `$a_arr` with 3 items.

How to do that the most efficient way in PHP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [max()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.max.php) to determine the longest array.

```
$longest = max($a_arr, $b_arr, $c_arr);
// Will return the array with highest amount of items ($a_arr)
```

Combine it with [count()](https://www.php.net/count) to get the amount of items in the longest array.

```
$longest = max(count($a_arr), count($b_arr), count($c_arr));
// Will return the max number of items (3 in this case; length of $a_arr)
```

Comment: Thanks, but couldn't it be done using something simpler and without creating additinoal array?

Comment: @user2984974 Just fiddled around a bit and there is, see updated answer.

Comment: Incredible, I shall test it.

Comment: It should be `$longest = max(count($a_arr), count($b_arr), count($c_arr));`, [see here](http://codepad.org/U79gdYhB).

Comment: @GottliebNotschnabel You're right, that would return the maximum amount of items in any of the arrays. Updated the answer.

Comment: No, I was wrong here. The OP wants to "select [return?] the array with the highest number of items". So the `max()` can be called without the `count()`s, so the array itself is returned.

Comment: @GottliebNotschnabel Hmm, yeah. Now I'm confused too. Split the answer in two to demonstrate both cases, just to be sure :)

Comment: Right, I now did so :-)

Comment: Yes you can, bravo! But I'll nevet use it, not so rustic.

Answer (score 1):

I propose one method:

```
$a_arr = array( '0' => '45', '1' => '50', '2' => '100' );
$b_arr = array( '0' => 'apple' );
$c_arr = array( '0' => 'toyota', '1' => 'ferrari', );

$result = $a_arr;
$nmax = count($a_arr);

$n = count($b_arr);
if($n > $nmax)
{
  $nmax = $n;
  $result = $b_arr;
}

$n = count($c_arr);
if($n > $nmax)
{
  $nmax = $n;
  $result = $c_arr;
}

//
// compare other arrays...
//

//
// maximal elements: $nmax, $result here is the array with the maximum of items.
//
```

Comment: Laborious but all in all correct (I actually assume something like this is what the `max()` function does internally). +1

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun:

```
array_multisort(($c=array_map('count',(compact('a_arr','b_arr','c_arr')))),SORT_DESC,$c);
echo key($c) . ' = ' . current($c);
```